# Datatables trigger rowgroup click with search filter

Tags: datatables, grouping

I am building a Datatables application with the latest [row grouping extension](https://datatables.net/blog/2017-04-07#Usage).  I've successfully managed to have the table display the row groups initially as collapsed.  When using the datatables search filter, I'd like the rowgroup to expand to show rows containing filter matches.

I've set up a working [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/lbriquet/ua4yLscx/).  Can anyone help?

Previously I was able to do this with a live filter function.

```
oTable.live('filter',function() {
    clearTimeout(oTable.data('timeout'));
   var timeoutId = setTimeout(function(){
       if($('label:contains(Table search: ) input').val() != '') {
          $('.group-item-expander.collapsed-group').trigger('click');
       }
       else {
           $('.group-item-expander.expanded-group').trigger('click');
       }
   },1000);
   oTable.data('timeout',timeoutId);
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can enable and disable the rowgroup function while searching:

```
oTable.on('search', function() {
    if (oTable.search()) { // actually searching for some text
        oTable.rows().nodes().each(function(r) {
            r.style.display = ''; // show all previously collapsed rows
        });
        oTable.rowGroup().disable();
    } else {
        oTable.rowGroup().enable();
    }
});
```

See this updated [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/8tx0r27p/).

Comment: Thank you very much!  This is very helpful!  In the application I am working on the grouped column is hidden (data is redundant with the grouping row).  So, I've added a line to make the the column visible when the grouping is turned off during search results.
https://jsfiddle.net/lbriquet/6fmh7k5y/